# How can I export and important Notes stored on Gmail?

Tags: iphone, backup, gmail, notes.app

My phone has crashed and reset. my latest backup if from 2019. the only data I have left from the past two years are the notes which are stored also in Gmail.
I still didn't re-install the phone and restored the data from the 2019 data point, since I'm afraid it will cause all my newer notes to be deleted once it syncs back with Gmail. How do I prevent this from happening? How may I bulk export and later import all notes?

Answer (score 0):

When you store your notes online restoring your iPhone from backup doesn’t delete them.

Comment: that's not what I read: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/5392295?hl=en

Comment: That detail would be super to add to your question body with an edit @Stackaloo